# Laravel storage

Tags: laravel, server, path, storage

I installed a Laravel application on my apache2 server. I installed like an alias.
The address of the server is: 192.168.1.137
The address of Laravel application is : 192.168.1.137/intranet

Here the virtualhost configuration :

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
    Alias /intranet "/var/www/html/intranet/public"
    
    <Directory "/var/www/html/intranet/public">
       allow from all
       order allow,deny
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

It works well.

I have a problem with my storage path. I cannot open a pdf document. When I look with Firefox inspector it gives the path : 192.168.1.137/storage/document.pdf

I cannot open the document by url on the application. If I modify the url manually with Firefox inspector and I add intranet like this 192.168.1.137/intranet/storage/document.pdf

[path of url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBPxW.png)

It works.

I try to add intranet to my config filesystems file, but nothing.

Where I have to modify to obtain the right address ?

Here my configuration file :

```
  /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
| framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
| any other location as required by the application or its packages.
*/
'name' => 'Intranet',
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
| running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
| services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
|
*/
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'APP_DEBUG'),
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://192.168.1.137/intranet'),
/*
```

Here my filesystems

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
        // 'root'   => base_path(),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'rapports'=>[
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('../../../../../mnt/rapports'),
    ],
],
```

The path rapports works well.

Thank you for your help

Comment: have you ran php artisan storage:link command

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I send php artisan storage:link but it not works. When I put intranet like this: http://192.168.1.137/intranet/storage/document.pdf in my url browser it works.

Comment: where is document.pdf file located

Comment: intranet/storage/app/122/repports/document.pdf

Comment: you cant access from there directly.you must put your files under intranet/storage/app/public/122/repports/document.pdf

Comment: you can do outside public but it will be extra work like file get content and then stream it

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are located in outside of public folder in storage.If you want to access files public then it should be placed under

```
storage/app/public/
```

we can see configuration in `fielsystem.php`

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Also make sure to run `php artisan storage:link` this will create shortcut in storage folder

Comment: Here my .htaccess in public folder on intranet/public/.htaccess

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteBase /intranet
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: yes.issue is you are not storing files in storage/app/public/ this path

Comment: I move app in storage/public, and I did a link with php artisan. It not works. I always same url without intranet. http://192.168.1.137/storage instead intranet/storage. When I make intranet a principal application like 192.168.1.137, not alias it works. It is only when I configure intranet like an alias that happens

Comment: you should place your images under storage/app/public/imagefolder/a.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to open a pdf document.
Here how :

I changed .env, APP_URL= for http://192.168.1.137/intranet
I had a problem in my view. It was like this :

```
success: function (data) {
   $('#iframe').attr('src', '/storage/' + data) 
   $('#dlrpt').attr('href', '/download/pdf/' + data)        
   $('#reportPreview').modal('show')
}
```

The path '/storage/'+data sent the url at the root of the site it was 192.168.1.137.
But I wanted to have 192.168.1.137/intranet

I changed like this :

In my vue.js data:

```
config: {!! json_encode(config('app.url')) !!},
```

Now config return 192.168.1.137/intranet

```
success: function (data) {
   $('#iframe').attr('src', self.config+'/storage/' + data) 
   $('#dlrpt').attr('href', '/download/pdf/' + data)        
   $('#reportPreview').modal('show')
}
```

It work !

It important to have a good configuration in .htaccess on the public folder.
like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteBase /intranet
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Thank you for your help.